# $A \cong B'$ and $B \cong A'$ , then $A \cong B$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $A'$ and $B'$ - subgroups of finitely generated abelian groups $A$ and $B$. And $A \cong B'$ , $B \cong A'$, then $A \cong B$.

My attempt : we know that subgroup of finitely generated group is finitely generated , so number of generating elements in $A'$ and $B$ are equals (also for $B'$ and $A$) , hence $\dim A = \dim B$ and they are $A \cong B$.
Am I right ?

Comment: Same number of generators doesn't mean $A \cong B$. Give a name to the isomorphisms and look at their composition, image, kernel.

Comment: Let $f : A \to B$ : $f(e_{i}) = h_{i}$?

Comment: If you "identify" $B$ and $A'$, then your question boils down to $A$ being isomorphic to a subgroup of itself ($A'$), and what happens with subgroups between $A'$ and $A$. Can you handle this case?

Comment: @SteveD dont understand your idea.

Comment: Are you using the structure theorem for f.g. abelian groups? Are you aware of torsion subgroups, and torsion-free abelian groups?

Comment: Yes, I know about them

Comment: Then I would try to do this question separately for the torsion, and torsion-free, parts.

Comment: @SteveD so what's exactly wrong in my proof?

Comment: Your proof is fine if both $A$ and $B$ are torsion free.  You have not yet handled torsion.

Comment: @SteveD what about this $A \cong B'$ => $A=Tor(A) \oplus A_{f} \cong Tor(B') \oplus B'_{f}$ so there must be equal $rk(Tor(A))=rk(Tor(B))$ and after all we have $A \cong B$ (we mapping $Tor(A)$ to $Tor(B)$). Does it better ?

Comment: I would suggest posting an answer to your own question, and letting others (including me) comment and vote on that answer.  This way the question gets an answer, and you get feedback on this new approach.

Comment: @SteveD thanks a lot

Comment: @SteveD added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

As we know $A = Tor (A) \oplus A_{free}$ and $B = Tor(B) \oplus B_{free}$ , so we have that. $B' \in B$ is finitely generated (as a subgroup of finitely generated group) and $B' = Tor(B') \oplus B_{free}$ and $A \cong B'$. Hence $rk(Tor(A)) = rk(Tor(B'))$ and also for $A' \in A$ and $B$. Because subgroup contains less or equal elements than a group we have : $rkA = rkB$ and $Tor(A) \cong Tor(B)$. So there must be isomorphism (because of isomorphism of subgroups save the order).